# Quarkus Opentelemetry Context

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream, quarkus, open-telemetry

The opentelemetry context is bound to the running thread which means the context needs to be propagated for any new threads being used. However, i am trying to see how the below code works:

sampleList.parallelStream().foreach(e -> e.process()); // example code

here the span on the process method is coming up as a separate trace as it's in a different thread. the only way to make it work is by adding a parentContext.makeCurrent() code around it. I feel this is a bit clumsy. Any ideas/suggestions on how to propagate the context without having to explicitly do it?

Thank you
SG

Answer (score 0):

This will happen because that piece of code uses the unmanaged ForkJoinPool to execute the tasks.
If you use a managed executor, that context propagation is handled by the framework.

See: https://quarkus.io/guides/context-propagation#sharing-configured-cdi-instances-of-managedexecutor-and-threadcontext

Moreover, it's not recommended to use `sampleList.parallelStream().*` in a managed framework like Quarkus (and many others) because the ForkJoinPool is a limited shared resource. You should create your own executor services for your business logic.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an example of how i can traverse through the list using executor services?

Comment: I have tried to change it to use Mutiny Uni to something like this: Uni<List<EntityObj>> entries =
                Uni.createFrom().item(List.of()); and then tried to access them using             entries.onItem().invoke(l -> {
                LOGGER.info(" no of items ({})", l.size());
            });
but this code doesn't get invoked and i don't see the # of items being logged. What is wrong with this code?